# Multiplication, sum and Cholesky decomposition of sparse matrices

Tags: julia, sparse-matrix

I'm trying to solve a system of differential equations involving variational inequalities. I'm currently using the LCP solver in LCPsolve.jl. I've profiled my code and found that the bottleneck is in lines 216-219 [here](https://github.com/junyuan-chen/LCPsolve.jl/blob/9bac1e787a5d5de763d51f0214db7fd0c2cf374a/src/solver.jl#L216-L219). More specifically, the profiler highlights the multiplication and sum in:

```
H = Jk'*Jk + μ*I
```

where `Jk` is a sparse matrix with size that varies within the `for` loop (but always smaller than 150x150) and

```
typeof(Jk) = SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64}
typeof(μ) = Float64
```

It also seems that those steps also allocate memory. The other operation highlighted by the profiler is

```
-(cholesky(H)\Jphi)
```

where

```
typeof(H) = SparseMatrixCSC{Float64, Int64}
typeof(Jphi) = Vector{Float64}
```

Is there a way to improve the performance and/or memory allocation of those steps? Thank you!

Comment: I think this will be faster and more accurate if you use Qr rather than the normal equations.

Comment: Hi Oscar, could you provide more details? I have tried using `qr`. However, I'm not getting the same results when H is a sparse matrix. Here is what I mean: `A = rand(100,100);
b = rand(100);
x1 = A\b;
Q, R = qr(A);
x2 = inv(factorize(R))*(Q'*b);
isapprox(x1, x2);

A = sprand(100,100,0.1);
b = rand(100);
x1 = A\b;
aux = qr(A);
x2 = inv(factorize(aux.R))*(aux.Q'*b);
isapprox(x1, x2);` In the second case with sparse matrix A, i'm not getting the same result. So I don't know how to implement your suggestion.